# Javascript how to properly await for a function before triggering the next one?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await

I'm having a issue with await and async functions where a function that should await for the completion of a fetch command triggers before it's done, hence i'm getting undefined value errors.

here is the function executing fetch:

```
async function BoardGet() {

        let conjunction = "Bearer " + responseToken.response.token 

        var myHeaders = new Headers()
        myHeaders.append("Authorization", conjunction)
        myHeaders.append("Content-Type", "application/json")

        var raw = JSON.stringify({})

        var requestOptions = {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: myHeaders,
            //body: raw,
            redirect: 'follow'
        }

        fetch("https://link-to-my-database", requestOptions)
            .then(response => response.text())
            .then(function(result) {
                let tempAvailableBoards = result
                availableBoards = JSON.parse(tempAvailableBoards)
                console.log("available boards: ", availableBoards)
            })
            .catch(error => console.log('error', error))
```

just fetches a JSON file which gets parsed into a variable. The problem is when I call my 2nd function which uses **availableBoards** and even though I used await, which from my understanding should force the next codeblock to wait, doesn't

```
async function BoardCheck() {

        await BoardGet()

        //check for board before creating a new one, if board already created return
        for(i = 0; i < availableBoards.response.data.length; i++) {
            if(boardId == availableBoards.response.data[i].fieldData._id_Miro_MiroBOARD) {
                console.log("This board is already in the database, now exiting this board create....")
                recordId = availableBoards.response.data[i].recordId // denotes filemaker data id for easier access (1 less loop)
                return
            }
            else if(i == availableBoards.response.data.length) {
                console.log("Borad not found, creating it...")
                BoardCreate()
            }
        }
    }
```

I get this error: Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'response' of undefined
at BoardCheck
After the Error I get response from BoardGet, judging by that await doesn't make the code actually await

Am I using await in a wrong way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't return a `Promise` that you can `await` from your `BoardGet` function. Write `return` before your `fetch()` call inside the function:

```
async function BoardGet() {

   // ...

   // return the promise
   return fetch("https://link-to-my-database", requestOptions)
            .then(response => response.text())
            .then(function(result) {
                let tempAvailableBoards = result
                availableBoards = JSON.parse(tempAvailableBoards)
                console.log("available boards: ", availableBoards)
            })
            .catch(error => console.log('error', error))
}
```

Comment: The word `async` in front of this function is unnecessary in this snippet.

Comment: Debatable. It marks a function that returns a `Promise`. Which is the case right here, so I don't think it is unnecessary, even though we don't use any `await` inside the `async` function @Adam

Comment: It's not debatable - if you removed `async`, there would be zero effect - the definition of "unnecessary". `async` also doesn't "mark" anything, it's allows you to use `await`. If you aren't using `await`, then you don't need `async`

Comment: It is indeed unnecessary. Whether it does any harm is debatable.

Comment: Thank you, this worked. I must have overlooked this step it in the async guides. Will accept your answer

Comment: @Adam there would be zero effect *for the code execution* but there would be an effect for communicating intent *to other programmers*. That can include yourself in the future. If you see the signatures `async foo()` and `bar()` which one would you say returns a promise and which one would you not be sure of? Some editors might only show you the signature, after all. Alternatively, you could just look it up yourself. Having to read the code further takes a non-zero amount of time. You're arguing for adding more dev time just because 5 bytes are *slightly* superfluous but not incorrect.

Comment: @VLAZ - Especially for programmers who are new-ish to async, mixing `async/await` AND **explicit Promises** is definitely confusing code. If you're going to use `async`, then do it fully and put `await` with a `try-catch` in the body of the function.

Comment: @Adam so, we should only write code for people who are unlikely to understand it? We should never write code for anybody even past beginner level?

Comment: @Adam I just don't think that it is necessary to change everything to `async/await`. Why should I change his code more than what fixes the problem, if there are no other problems with it except your personal disbelieves. I think that would be a lot more confusing to the beginner.